# Query last 12 months of data where year and month are separate columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to figure out a way to query the last 12 completed months of data, so it would go up to last month and ignore this month.

I've done this before when the table had a date column, but this new table I'm working with separates the date into two month and year columns.

How would I go about this in SQL Server 2012?

Thanks in advance.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CalendarYear    CalendarMonth   TotalSales
2014            3               35.00   
2014            4               220.00  
2015            2               243.00  
2015            5               17.93   
2015            6               216.36  
2015            10              370.93  
2015            12              350.00
2016            1               116.75  
2016            2               13.78
```

DESIRED OUTPUT (assuming current time is in February 2016):

```
CalendarYear    CalendarMonth   TotalSales
2015            2               243.00  
2015            5               17.93   
2015            6               216.36  
2015            10              370.93  
2015            12              350.00
2016            1               116.75
```

Comment: show us sample data and desire output, that will help a lot

Comment: Just added a small snippet of what I'm working with. Hope that is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've assumed the Day part is always the 1st of the month.

```
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CalendarYear + '-' + CalendarMonth + '- 01') >= DATEADD(mm, -12, GETDATE())
```

The above assumes the columns are strings. Below I've done a version where the columns are numbers.

```
WHERE
  CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(CalendarYear AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(CalendarMonth AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '-01') >= DATEADD(mm, -12, GETDATE())
```

Comment: That looks like it ought to work, but for some reason the convert is giving some strange dates. When I put CONVERT(DATETIME, CalendarYear + '-' + CalendarMonth + '- 01') into my select, it gives me 1905-07-19 00:00:00.000 as an output when CalendarYear is 2015 and CalendarMonth is 11.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the columns were strings. I've edited the answer to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That appears to work. It doesn't take into account the last full month, but that's something I should be able to figure out from here.

Comment: WHERE
  CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(CalendarYear AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(CalendarMonth AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, -13, @now) AND DATEADD(mm, -1, @now)

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply same code/logic to year and month you want data.

```
 where to_date(year || month, 'YYYYMM') 
   between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -12) and trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using that has trunc and sysdate?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that answer when I was searching it, but I think that only works for Oracle.